# Change date picker format (day, month, year) not to 1.7.2023 but 01.07.2023

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple code (Kotlin) for PickerDate with binding to the EditText field and it works, BUT! The output format is 1.7.2023, and I need the 01.07.2023 format.

```
lateinit var dateEdt: EditText

 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change)

dateEdt = findViewById(R.id.date1)
        dateEdt.setOnClickListener {
            var c = Calendar.getInstance()
            var day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            var month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            var year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(

                this,
                { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                    val dat = (dayOfMonth.toString() + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year)
                },
                year,
                month,
                day )
            datePickerDialog.show()
        }
```

**Not working**

```
if(month < 10){

        month = "0" + month;
    }
    if(day < 10){

        day  = "0" + day ;
    }
    searchText.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);
```

**Not working**

```
Date d = new Date(year, month, day);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm");
dateEdt = dateFormatter.format(d);
```

**Not working**

```
calendar.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String dateEdt = format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlSuJy9SfzvFwwzaCtmmhb6Ahi1_voypW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods that are not working for you are the only workarounds to get the data string in your desired format maybe the you use these methods is faulty, anyways I am adding my snippet for reference.

```
   dateEdt.setOnClickListener {
            var c = Calendar.getInstance()
            var day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            var month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            var year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(

                this,
                { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
             val day = if(dayOfMonth < 10) "0$dayOfMonth" else "$dayOfMonth"
           val month = if(monthOfYear + 1 < 10) "0$monthOfYear" else "${monthOfYear+1}" 
            val date = day+month+"$year"
            dateEdt.text = date
                },
                year,
                month,
                day )
            datePickerDialog.show()
        }
```

Comment: Thks for answer, but not working dateEdt.text = date (error)

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: dateEdt.setText(date) - That's right. Passing the object to setText, not to a variable. 
Otherwise, your construction with "if" "else" in this bundle works fine. Thanks for the help. Good luck!